# 2D array (pointer to pointer)

Tags: c

I want to fill 2D array with random numbers and then call it in `main` function and print it. But I can't access the function `FillMatrix` from `main`.

```
#define R 12 //row
#define S 10 //column

void FillMatrix(int m[][S], int row);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    time_t t;

    // POINTER TO POINTER
    int **mat = (int **)malloc(R * sizeof(int *));
    if ((mat = (int**)malloc(R*sizeof(int))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<R; i++)
        mat[i] = (int *)malloc(S * sizeof(int));

    FillMatrix(mat, R); //<- This line is the problem

    // RAND 0 - 1000
}

void FillMatrix(int m[][S], int row)
{
    int i, j;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < S; j++)
            m[i][j] = rand() % 1000 + 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding the line `void FillMatrix(int m[][S], int row);` before your main.

Comment: Do you want a C or a C++ answer?

Comment: C != C++, and in general you should only tag the language you are writing/compiling (for example, prefer container classes in C++, then smart pointers before going to raw memory allocation, and in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`).

Comment: I want answer in C. And i edited the code so there is a main function now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(mat = (int**)malloc(R*sizeof(int))` allocates the wrong amount of space; the type should be `sizeof(int *)` or equivalently `sizeof *mat`. Also you leak the memory you just allocated on the previous line.

To fix this, change `if ((mat = (int**)malloc(R*sizeof(int))) == NULL)`  to `if ( mat == NULL )` .

---

Also, `int **` is not compatible with `int[][S]`.  `int **` represents an array where each line is a separate allocation, however `int [][S]` represents one contiguous memory block.  You must choose which of those two approaches you want to use.

If you want to use the separate rows, then change the function to `void FillMatrix(int **m, int row)` (and it would be good style to have the number of columns as a parameter, instead of using the global `S`).

Or if you want to use the contiguous memory block, change the allocation line to `int (*mat)[S] = malloc(R * sizeof *mat);`

Comment: I changed the function to 'void FillMatrix(int **m, int row)'. But now i get "cannot convert argument from 'int**' to 'int [][S]'".

Comment: If you get that error then you didn't actually change the function like you said. Maybe you forgot to change both the prototype and the definition

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're code is off a bit.  I'm going to assume that your main function starts right before `int i, j;` and ends after the call to `FillMatrix(mat, R);`.

If that is the case then you need to either move your function definition of FillMatrix before you start your main function OR you need to forward declare your FillMatrix function before your main function.

The issue is that your main function cannot "see" your FillMatrix function.  Order is VERY important.  If something has not been declared, defined, or in some way shown to exist AT THE POINT IN QUESTION then it doesn't exist as far as the compiler is concerned.  Think of it like trying to access some variable before you declare it in a function.